# I am trying to update qt designed GUI of label dynamically with navdata values of drone. When I run this script it is giving following error

Tags: python, qt

> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py",
>   line 720, in _invoke_callback
>       cb(msg)   File "PGUI.py", line 34, in ReceiveNavdata
>       form1 =  setupUi() NameError: global name 'setupUi' is not defined

```
class Ui_Form(object):

 def __init__(self):
    pass

def ReceiveNavdata(self):
    battery = self.batteryPercent#self.batteryPercent
    state = self.state
    altitude = self.altd
    vx = self.vx
    vy = self.vy
    vz = self.vz
    rotX = self.rotX
    rotY = self.rotY
    rotZ = self.rotZ
    # vx1 = navdata.vx
    # battery = 100
    print("%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f" % (battery,state,altitude,vx,vy,vz,rotX,rotY,rotZ))
    form1 =  setupUi()
    self.setupUi.Vx_D.setText(vx)

def setupUi(self, Form):
  Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
  Form.resize(867, 602)
  self.Vx_D = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
  self.Vx_D.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 300, 78, 21))
  self.Vx_D.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Vx_D"))

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
  Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
  self.Vx_D.setText(_translate("Form", "Vx_D", None))
if __name__ == "__main__":
 import sys

 app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 Form = QtGui.QWidget()
 ui = Ui_Form()
 ui.setupUi(Form)
 Form.setWindowTitle("GUI")  
Form.setGeometry(0,0,1000,500)
Form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Which is line 34 and 720?

Comment: The setupUi method is not a class method. Take a look at [classes in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: It looks like you didn't indent the code properly, so `setupUi` is a regular function and not a method of the `Ui_Form` class.

Comment: Thank You for your replies:) @Carpetsmoker code is indented correctly. Here not in order. It was generated by  using pyuic4. setupUi is method of Ui_Form

Comment: I have hard coded value for vx = self.vx like vx = 100 just to check weather it will reflect on UI or not. But its not!!! any suggestions how to change label values dynamically ?

Comment: @user3151902 Sure!! Thank you:) I am a beginner need to follow tutorials

Comment: @user3151902 Consider creating a answer of your comment or the OP may do it himself.

Comment: Change `self.setupUi.Vx_D.setText(vx)` to `self.Vx_D.setText(vx)` and delete `form1 =  setupUi()`

Comment: @eyllanesc I have changed and tried! But No JOy!!  After creating a lable do I need connect a signal ?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have changed and run.     
self.Vx_D.setText(vx)
AttributeError: 'Navdata' object has no attribute 'Vx_D'   

It is throwing me this error.
please give suggestions to resolve this ?

Comment: At what time do you call the ReceiveNavdata() function, where you create the attributes self.batteryPercent, self.state, and the other attributes. your code has many shortcomings, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45996853/edit) your question and correct those silly mistakes.

Comment: If I try to access the variables of ReceiveNavdata() method.
it is giving me following error.

 NameError: global name 'vx' is not defined

Comment: I recommend that before you continue with your project you learn a little of OOP, especially implemented in python. only the attributes of the class can be accessed, not the variables that are created in the methods.

Comment: Your code is horrible and non-testable.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank You:) Actually, I have added some part of the code here. My GUI contains more buttons and labels. That is  why I have avoided to put all and  may be it is looking bad to you.If you please share you id. I will mail you the code

Comment: Sir in SO you must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you think not to place the code to be extensive place the necessary and the other up to places like github, dropbox, drive or similar and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

The `setupUi` method is not a class method. Take a look at [classes in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).